# Reconstruct an image from an array

Tags: python, image, numpy, python-imaging-library

I have a matrix with eight files, each file has eight values, the first is this one:

`[[252, 244, 255], [255, 240, 251], [255, 238, 246], [255, 236, 249], [247, 224, 251], [232, 193, 238], [220, 151, 209], [214, 119, 184]]`

I want to reconstruct an image from this matrix, I already settled in array for all the matrix, the previous list is for example of the first file.

```
data = np.asarray(data)
data = np.reshape(data, (hh, w, 3))
img = Image.fromarray(data.astype('uint8'), 'RGB')
img.save('./imgs/image.jpg')
```

Data is the array with all the values, `hh` and `wm` is height and weight of the matrix.
I am using this code, but the image that is giving to me is https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEAk1.jpg. The colors don´t match, for make sure of that I used https://imagecolorpicker.com.

What´s wrong?

Comment: can you share hh and w?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide all of the data (i.e. provide a [mre]).

Comment: Sometimes image libraries and numpy have differing definitions for the last (color) axis. Some define it as RGB and others as BGR. Try reversing your last axis and then saving. `img = Image.fromarray(data[..., ::-1].astype('uint8'), 'RGB')`

Comment: Please add image showing how you expect it to look!